# how can i create drowdownbutton with Riverpod Notifier?

Tags: flutter, provider, dropdownbutton, riverpod, flutter-change-notifier

I want to create DropDownButton with changenotifierProvider in Riverpod, but i can not write nicely my code. Please help me. I suppose, i just wrote 'watch' method, but i do not know how to read it. So, it should show the item which is chosen, and also it should be update with provider.Category.

My DropDownButton code is here:

```
Widget dropdownButton(BuildContext context,watch) {
    String constantValue = "League Of Legends";
      final postProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<PostProvider>((ref) => PostProvider());
      
      final provider = watch(postProvider);
      return Consumer(
        builder: (context, watch, _) {
       
          
      return DropdownButton(
            value: provider.postCategory ?? constantValue,
            
            onChanged: (newValue) {
               provider.postCategory = newValue;
              
            },
            items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
                .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                onTap: () => value,
                value: value ?? constantValue,
                child: Text(value ?? constantValue),
              );
            }).toList());
        },
              
      );
    
  }
```

Here my DropDownButton Image: ( when i choose any item of the list, it can not work properly. It always pick the first one (It picks "League of Legends").
[image]

I select steam but card categoty shows League of legends
[image: I select steam but ,]

Comment: Use your IDE to find out the type and possible methods on `provider`.  And your postProvider needs to be created outside of a build method and persisted, so either in the State scope, or in a global scope.

Comment: please give me the solution i tried but i can not understand exactly.. +++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final postProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<PostProvider>((ref) => PostProvider());

class PostProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String _postCategory;

  String get postCategory => _postCategory;

  categoryOnChanged(String value) {
    if (value.isEmpty) {
      return _postCategory;
    }
    _postCategory = value;
    print(_postCategory);
    return notifyListeners();
  }
}

class DropDownPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DropDownPageState createState() => _DropDownPageState();
}

class _DropDownPageState extends State<DropDownPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Dropdown Riverpod issue"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Center(
          child: _DropDownWidgetConsumer(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _DropDownWidgetConsumer extends ConsumerWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, ScopedReader watch) {
    final category = watch(postProvider).postCategory;
    return DropdownButton(
      hint: Text("Choose category"),
      value: category,
      items: <String>["League Of Legends", "Steam", "Csgo"]
          .map((e) => DropdownMenuItem<String>(
        
                onTap: () => e,
                value: e ?? category,
                child: Text(e ?? "$category"),
              ))
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        context.read(postProvider).categoryOnChanged(value);
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: yes it worked, but still there is a problem. It do not update the ' _postCategory '. It always pick 'League of legends'.

Comment: what shows that i doesnt update the _postCategory value. it does update, if not when you hot reload you would have gotten League of legends

Comment: dude i mean, for example i select 'Steam' in items, and it should show 'Steam' on the card. ( Where is the card? Look the photo above, behind the dropdown, green card)

Comment: i think you can take this existing code and add it up.

Comment: i answered based on the question you gave. Maybe you can update the question to add the card

Comment: i have already copy and paste them :D but wait i will add photo

Comment: recopy and repaste it again. ive updated my solution

Comment: u can pop off the dialog with the selected category and setState the card with the updated category

Comment: A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: how we can update this... I select items now, but it has to be set. It shows steam, but when i click submit button, still it picks 'League of legends'. help about this